# AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException: The local appium server has not been started

Tags: java, node.js, appium

Im trying to **start Appium server** programmatically from Java
(OS: Windows7 x64)

- using first method from source: http://www.automationtestinghub.com/3-ways-to-start-appium-server-from-java/

The code that I use for starting Appium sever is:

---

```
  public void startServer() {
    //Set Capabilities
    cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
    cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

    //Build the Appium service
    builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
    builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
    builder.usingPort(4723);
    builder.withCapabilities(cap);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
    builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL, "error");

    //added by myself:
    builder.usingDriverExecutable(new File("C:/node/node.exe"));
    builder.withAppiumJS(new File("C:/Users/[user]/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/appium/lib/appium.js"));


    //Start the server with the builder
    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
    service.start();
}
```

I'm **getting an exception**:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.appium.java_client.service.local.AppiumServerHasNotBeenStartedLocallyException: The local appium server has not been started. The given Node.js executable: C:\node\node.exe Arguments: [C:\Users\Dima\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js, --port, 4723, --address, 127.0.0.1, --log-level, error, --session-override, --default-capabilities, {\"noReset\": \"false\"}]
```

Process output: C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\lib\appium.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import _ from 'lodash';                                                           ^^^^^^

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:188:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:609:3
```

I tried every way to start Appium server from the source, but second one causes to the same, but third causes to error [image]

Any ideas? Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: Change appium.js to main.js - same location.

Comment: oh it was my mistake in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did mistake in code. Fixed method is:

```
     public static String runAppiumService(int appiumPort) {

        //Build parameters for appium server:
        AppiumServiceBuilder appiumServiceBuilder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        appiumServiceBuilder.usingPort(appiumPort)
                .withIPAddress(APPIUM_IP)
                .withAppiumJS(new File(getAppiumJsPath()))
                .withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE)
                .withLogFile(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/resources/appium_server_logs" + Thread.currentThread().getId()));
        AppiumDriverLocalService service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(appiumServiceBuilder);
        service.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at official documentation:
https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/docs/The-starting-of-an-app-using-Appium-node-server-started-programmatically.md

Make sure your env setup for Appium is correct and that appium service/client versions are compatible.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ServerManager {
    AppiumDriverLocalService service;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ServerManager sm = new ServerManager();
        sm.startServer();
        
    }
    public void startServer() {
        final DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
        //Set Capabilities
        
        cap.setCapability("noReset", "false");

        //Build the Appium service
        AppiumServiceBuilder builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder = new AppiumServiceBuilder();
        builder.withIPAddress("127.0.0.1");
        builder.usingPort(4723);
        builder.withCapabilities(cap);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.SESSION_OVERRIDE);
        builder.withArgument(GeneralServerFlag.LOG_LEVEL,"error");

        //Start the server with the builder
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildService(builder);
        service.start();
    }

    public void stopServer() {
        service.stop();
    }
```

}